# How can I substitute ngmodel by ngclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now my code uses ng-model:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="padesVisual.selected">
```

However, I need to change to ng-click:

```
<li>
  <a href="#PAdES" aria-controls="PAdES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
     ng-click="VerificaPades(verifica)">PAdES</a>
</li>
```

I tried to use this function:

```
$scope.VerificaPades = function(verifica) {
    if ($scope.padesVisual.selected) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are showing to different examples. Do you want to use ng-click in the HTML-snippet which is using ng-model?

Comment: I'd like use only ng-click. I'll delete ng-model.

Comment: It's really unclear what the goal is here. Do you want to toggle the value of `$scope.padesVisual.selected`? That's just `$scope.padesVisual.selected = !$scope.padesVisual.selected;`. See it in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/0umwww7z/).

Comment: I need to do the function of ng-model on ng-click. Ng-model is boolean, right? How can I do this on ng-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below demonstrates one way to implement a boolean toggle using `ng-click`. The main point of interest is the `VerificadaPades` function, which actually toggles the boolean model.

```js
var eAssinatura = angular.module("pades", []);

eAssinatura.controller('AdicionarEditarFormatoAssinaturaDialogController', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {
       
        $scope.padesVisual = {
            positions: [],
            fields: [],
            selected: false,
            sealStamp: { isSelected: false, image: '' }
        }

        $scope.VerificaPades = function () {
            $scope.padesVisual.selected = !$scope.padesVisual.selected;
        }

       
    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="pades" ng-controller="AdicionarEditarFormatoAssinaturaDialogController">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#CAdES" aria-controls="CAdES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CAdES</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#PAdES" aria-controls="PAdES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="VerificaPades()">
      PAdES</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="CAdES">CAdES</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="PAdES">
            <div class="row" ng-show="padesVisual.selected">
              Selected
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works!! But I have another problem. Because I use in tabs like this:

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#CAdES" aria-controls="CAdES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CAdES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#PAdES" aria-controls="PAdES" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="VerificaPades(verifica)">PAdES</a></li>
    </ul>

When #CAdES is active and I click in #PAdES <span ng-show="padesVisual.selected">Selected</span> doesn't show.

Comment: Please don't post that much code in a comment. It's much easier to read in the question itself. Just update your question with the new information.

Comment: I put my code here, but there is something wrong. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the new information. Do not post it as an answer unless the changes you posted solved your problem.

Comment: Any model data you want to access needs to be in the scope of the element where you want it displayed. In other words, you have to place your "ng-controller" directive (or whatever directive uses the specified controller) on the parent element of the page in order for clicks on one element to be relevant to elements outside of it.